# Parse JSON from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am building a web site and I use a url which returns a JSON response, like:

```
{name:mark; status:ok}
```

I would like to obtain the name, using only JavaScript or jQuery in my HTML page.

Can somebody help me to do this?

Comment: Your JSON is bogus. Other than that, did you try searching for "jquery json"?

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at jQuery's [`.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method, which will make it really easy for you.

```
$.getJSON('yourURL.php', function(data) {
  alert(data.name);
});
```

If you need more flexibility you should have a look at [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead. `.getJSON()` is really just a short hand for the `.ajax()` method, suitable for making simple requests to fetch JSON. With `.ajax()` you will have a lot of more options - specifying an error handler for instance, and much more.

Answer (score 4):

```
$.getJSON("URL", function(json) {
   alert("JSON Data: " + json.name);
 });
```

I guess this will work for you.

If you want to Pass parameters then here is code

```
$.getJSON("URL", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(json) {
    alert("JSON Data: " + json.name);
    });
```

Refer [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: I tried it...in my html page I put it but it doesn't work...;(!!! I put in my page this <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>...but nothing!!!

Comment: it would be great if you can add more code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me';
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        alert(data.name);
    });
});
```