# Parsing json and show image in popop

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write an xkcd extension for chrome in javascript.
To obtain the url to the latest image, I fetch the JSON from http://dynamic.xkcd.com/api-0/jsonp/comic/ and try to parse it. Obviously, that doesn't quite work.

Neither is the json parsed correctly, nor is the image from the hardcoded url shown in the popup. How can I solve these problems?

So my questions are:

1. How can I retrieve the image url from the json?
2. How can I insert the image to the popup?

Here is my code:
(I followed a tutorial, that's why there's still some flicker-snippets left...)

The manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "xkcd extension",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "The first xkcd extension that I made.",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
"http://www.xkcd.com/"
]
}
```

The popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
        body {
            min-width:357px;
            overflow-x:hidden;
        }

        img {
            margin:5px;
            border:2px solid black;
            vertical-align:middle;
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        showPhotos();

        function showPhotos() {
            //                var url="http://xkcd.com/info.0.json";
            var url = "http://dynamic.xkcd.com/api-0/jsonp/comic/";
            alert(url);
            //                var imgURL;
            //                $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            //                    alert(data.img);
            //                    imgURL=data.img;
            //                });
            //alert(imgURL);

            var img = document.createElement("image");
            alert(img);
            img.src = 'http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wrong_superhero.png';
            alert(img.src);
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var img = document.createElement("image");`

should definitely be

`var img = document.createElement("img");`

Comment: I'm aware of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140632/parse-json-from-url), but for unknown reason getJSON just doesn't give me the wanted attribute

Comment: OK, the other point is that you are trying to invoke `showPhotos()` **before** your DOM (and `document.body` in particular) is ready. Rather than invoking `showPhotos()` directly, invoke it in an `onload` handler: `<body onload="showPhotos()">` - this worked for me.

Comment: Does this solve your issue? If so, you can accept the answer :)