# Javascript code for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a tiny extension for chrome.
I have exactly [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/y6MD3/) in my popup.html,
the manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
"name": "xkcd 2",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "The first xkcd extension that I made.",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
"http://www.xkcd.com/"
]
}
```

Contrary to the run on jsfiddle, there are no alerts shown when I click the icon of my extension in chrome.

Is there any code that chrome does not like?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope, there are non, it just doesn't work in chrome

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in [your other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150824/parsing-json-and-show-image-in-popop), you should never modify your DOM other than from the code run AFTER your DOM is ready but instead run it in the `load` event handler for your page. If you look at the JSFiddle page code, you will see that your code is run exactly in the onload handler. Other non-deferred launching options (the left column on JSFiddle) move your script into the `<body>` element. You might try doing that as well (rather than including the script in your `<head>`).

Comment: Thanks four your answer, I moved the entire script part to the body. Unfortunately, the alerts are still not shown

Comment: I'm fairly new to script coding, how can I ensure that my DOM is fully loaded when I modify it?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150824/parsing-json-and-show-image-in-popop#comment11515268_9150873) I explained how. To reiterate, you should write your `BODY` tag as <body onload="handleOnLoad()">` and make all your code the contents of the `handleOnLoad()` function:
    `function handleOnLoad() {
    ...
    }`

Comment: If I understood you correctly, all the script code is supposed to be in the handleOnLoad-function, the function is in the body wihtin the script-tags, just like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pqNZY/). Again, it only runs properly in jsfiddle, not in my extension..

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest asks for permissions to `http://www.xkcd.com/` but you make your actual request to `http://dynamic.xkcd.com/`. Try asking permission for `http://*.xkcd.com/`